# Delete AWS S3 buckets using boto3 - AttributeError

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm attempting to delete an S3 bucket using boto3 library

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
response = bucket.delete()
```

I get the following error:

```
"errorType": "AttributeError",
"errorMessage": "'S3' object has no attribute 'Bucket'"
```

I cannot see what's wrong... Thanks

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
import boto3    
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
bucket.delete()
```

Comment: are you using last version of boto3? or which version are you using?

Comment: I'm running my script on Lambda, which has version 1.4.4

Comment: are you sure there is no error on line `s3 = ...`? if you check in the lambda logs before the error you are describing?

Comment: just checked, there's no error before `bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')`

Comment: can you do a `print boto3.__version__` I think Lambda doesn't have the last version...

Answer (score 1):

I think doing this way is more robust. Since API doesn't allow non-empty bucket removals.

```
import boto3





BUCKET_NAMES = [
    "buckets",
    "to",
    "remove"
]

for bucket_name in BUCKET_NAMES:
    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    bucket_versioning = s3.BucketVersioning(bucket_name)
    if bucket_versioning.status == 'Enabled':
        bucket.object_versions.delete()
    else:
        bucket.objects.all().delete()
    response = bucket.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
s3resource = boto3.client('s3')
s3bucketlists = s3resource.list_buckets()
for bucket in s3bucketlists["Buckets"]:
    print(f' {bucket["Name"]}')
    abc = {bucket["Name"]}
    for i in abc:
        print(i)
        s3resource.delete_bucket(Bucket=i)
```

You can read the [detail](https://testertechie.com/how-to-delete-aws-s3-bucket-lists-using-python-boto3/)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

This is because the client interface (`boto3.client`) doesn't have `.Bucket()`, only `boto3.resource` does, so this would work:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
response = bucket.delete()
```

Quoted from the [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/resources.html):

> Resources represent an object-oriented interface to Amazon Web Services (AWS). They provide a higher-level abstraction than the raw, low-level calls made by service clients.

Generally speaking, if you are using boto3, resources should probably be your preferred interface most of the time.

Answer (score -2):

The error message contains 'S3' with capital S. I suspect a typo that's not pasted here since your code shows 's3' with lowercase s.

Personally, I'd just do it this way:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'my_bucket'
response = s3.delete_bucket(Bucket=bucket)
```

Comment: Your typo claim is wrong, boto3 or Python return back 'S3' for some reason.

You can test this code snippet out here and compare the output I got for it: https://pastebin.com/raw/XCm59Gvv